# Ignore param value in mockery test

Tags: go

I'm trying to write some tests using `.EXPECT()`, and I want to ignore the value of a parameter (SubmittedDate). The following is the test I've written

```
client.EXPECT().Process(param1, {
        Txn: {
            MemberId: memberId,
            UserId: userId,
            SubmittedAt: mock.Anything,
        },
    }).Return(true, nil).Once()
```

mock.Anything in the above statement is throwing the following error:

```
cannot use mock.Anything (untyped string constant "mock.Anything") as *timestamppb.Timestamp value in struct literal
```

Is there another way I can ignore the value of SubmittedAt, but declare the other expected values?

Comment: See [timestamppb doc](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/protobuf/types/known/timestamppb#New).

Comment: did you already tried `AnythingOfType("* timestamppb.Timestamp")` ?

Comment: @Matteo no I hadn't, thanks for suggesting! Would I just pass that in like this: 
SubmittedAt: mock.AnythingOfType("*timestamppb.Timestamp"). That seems to return the same error as the one in my question